# Query Error in php - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I found the error on my query

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') GROUP BY A.'model_id' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

my query

```
SELECT A.*,B.model_name, B.featured_image as model_image,B.model_price, V.max_value, V.min_value, GROUP_CONCAT(A.id ORDER BY A.id separator ',') as versions FROM ci_cars as A INNER JOIN v_cars as V ON A.id = V.car_id LEFT JOIN ci_carmodels as B ON A.model_id= B.id WHERE A.m_id IN () GROUP BY A.model_id
```

Comment: `A.m_id IN ()` - `()` is not a valid input to `IN`